# Is there a "natural" transitive action of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ on a set with 5 elements?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, permutations

I'm really looking for a "cute" way of showing that $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ is a double cover of $A_5$.  The sort of action I am looking for is something like the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_3)$, which shows $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ is a double cover of $S_4$.  Now that's cute.

Comment: Here's a related thread you may be interested in: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93762/

Answer (score 1):

You can ask this type of questions to GAP:

```
GAP4, Version: 4.4.12 of 17-Dec-2008, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
gap> g := SL(2,5);;
gap> 5 in List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g), c -> Index(g, Representative(c)));
true
gap>
```

There is in fact a unique conjugacy class of subgroups of index 5, isomorphic to SL(2,3).

Comment: Smart!  I was looking at conjugacy classes of elements but didn't think of looking at the subgroup lattice.  There's also a conjugacy class of subgroups isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$.