# Representation of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, geometry, reference-request, representation-theory

Can someone give me a proper reference (a book probably)for how a 3 dimensional representation of the Alternating group $A_5$ is related to the reflection group $H_3$ or the Icosahedral group ? Thanks

Comment: You may not consider this as a "proper reference", but this could be interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj5PE6r_Oeo (from the 12th min.)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130464