# Kernel and image of a homomorphism $SL(2,5)\to S_5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Since $SL(2,5)$ has a subgroup of index $5$, I can use the left coset action to define a homomorphism between $SL(2,5)$ and $S_5$. How can I find the kernel and the image of this homomorphism?

#### Progress

The kernel would be a normal subgroup of $SL(2,5)$. Other than the trivial ones there's the cyclic group of order $2$, but I'm not sure these are all of them.

Comment: Well, what are the possible kernels (i.e. what are the normal subgroups)?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Other than the trivial ones there's the cyclic group of order 2, but I'm not sure these are all of them.

Comment: $S_5$ has a trivial center.

Comment: related: [Elementary isomorphism between $PSL(2,5)$ and $A_5$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93762/) etc

Comment: This is appreciated, but I still can't quite see it.