# Why is $PGL_2(5)\cong S_5$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, exceptional-isomorphisms, groups-of-lie-type

Why is $PGL_2(5)\cong S_5$? And is there a set of 5 elements on which $PGL_2(5)$ acts?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/why-is-pgl2-4-isomorphic-to-a-5

Comment: If it helps, $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5))$ and $S_5\cong \operatorname{Aut}(A_5)$ and $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)\cong A_5$.  ([source](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/PGL(2,5)_is_isomorphic_to_S5))

Comment: I think this might be explained in some of those exceptional automorphisms of S6 papers. S5 acts on its 6 Sylow 5-subgroups, embedding it weirdly in S6. That embedding is the same as PGL(2,5) on its projective plane. So it shows S5 is isomorphic to PGL(2,5) instead of vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Speyer [explains](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119354/),

there are 15 involutions of $P^1(\mathbb F_5)$ without fixed points (one [might](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/six.html) call them «synthemes»). Of these 15 involutions 10 («skew crosses») lie in $PGL_2(\mathbb F_5)$ and 5 («true crosses») don't. The action of $PGL_2(\mathbb F_5)$ on the latter ones gives the isomorphism $PGL_2(\mathbb F_5)\to S_5$.