# On the relationship between $\text{SL}_2(5)$ and $A_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

I have two questions.

1. What is the quickest way to see from scratch that $\text{SL}_2(5)/\{\pm I\}$ is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_5$?
2. Does $\text{SL}_2(5)$ have any subgroups isomorphic to $A_5$?

Comment: For 2, it would be an index-two subgroup, so the kernel of a morphism to $\{\pm 1\}$, but $SL_2(5)$ is perfect, so that can't happen. For 1, I would look at the action on the projective line: that embeds $PSL_2(5)$ as an index-six subgroup of $A_6$, and then you have to show that $A_5$ is the only possibility (up to isomorphism, not up to conjugacy).

Comment: Can you show that $SL_2(5)$ has five Sylow 2-subgroups? Conjugation action on those then gives a homomorphism $\phi:SL_2(5)\to S_5$. Obviously the center will be in the kernel. It's probably not  too hard to show that the image is contained in $A_5$....

Comment: "not too hard" = obvious, once you know that $PSL_2(5)$ is simple (the sign morphism $PSL_2(5) \to S_5 \to \{\pm 1\}$ has to be trivial)

Comment: Yup. @PseudoNeo I wasn't sure whether we can assume simplicity of $PSL_2(5)$. :-)

Comment: Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/376464/11619).