# Simple group of order 168

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a simple group of order 168, I have to show that it has at least 14 elements of order 3.

Using Sylow's theorems I proved that if $n_3$ is the number of 3-Sylows then $n_3\in\{4,7,28\}$, but now I don't know how to continue, I have to exclude the possibility of $n_3=4$, could you help me?

Reading this question [Prove there is no element of order 6 in a simple group of order 168](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71768/prove-there-is-no-element-of-order-6-in-a-simple-group-of-order-168) I saw that actually $n_3=28$ could you explain me why?

Comment: If there were $4$ $3$-Sylow groups, your simple group $G$ would act on them by conjutation, giving a map $G\to S_4$. Can you get a contradiction from this?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402/

Answer (score 6):

The group $G$ acts by conjugation on the set of its own $3$-Sylow subgroups. That means that there is a homomorphism from $G$ into $S_{n_3}$, whose image is a transitive subgroup of $S_{n_3}$. Since $G$ is simple, the kernel of this map must be trivial, so $n_3!$ must be at least $168 = 2^3\times 3\times 7$.

This observation rules out $n_3=4$.

Comment: how can I rule out also the case $n_3=7$?

Comment: Dear Alex, please ask that *in the question body*. The comments to an answer is not the correct place where to ask a question!

Comment: @Mariano: To be fair, that is also in the body (third paragraph).

Comment: Eliminating the case of $7$ Sylow 3-groups can be done a variety of ways.  If there were $7$, you get a homomorphism into $S_7$, where an element of order $3$ looks like $(123)(456)$.  Now what does an element of order $2$ which centralizes this look like?