# Element of order 4 in PSL(2,7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please, I can't find an element of the subgroup of $A_7$ generated by $a=(1234567)$ and $b=(26)(34)$ with order 4.

If anybody could give me the combination of $a$ and $b$ I need, it would be fantastic. I have tried everything I swear. I have tried to find a matrix of $SL(3,2)$ with order $4$, generated by $[0 1 1, 0 0 1, 1 1 1]$ and $[1 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 1]$ and use an isomorphism (other matrices don't work with my isomorphism).

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Could it be that you're sitting in an exam?

Comment: Thenk you very much, but, how can I know how have we operated a and b to find this elements or isn't possible???

Comment: @MattN.: Sorry, sitting *in* an exam? You mean, you think he is sitting in an exam hall, with some gadget out actually asking questions on the internet?

Comment: @user1729 Yep. And if his friend Maria is not himself then I'd guess Maria is sitting there with him.

Comment: @MattN. How could you possibly think that? Why would you possibly think that - it isn't exactly the first thing which springs to mind...

Comment: @user1729 Because it has happened before. Back then in the good old times when people honestly declared that they were in an exam at that very moment and needed the answers _urgently_.

Comment: "Maria" is trying to edit this post; if "Maria" = "Rosa": then "Rosa" can edit the post without requiring approval.

Comment: @YACP Yep. ${}$

Comment: @amWhy If you look at the suggested edit you will find that it's written in first person singular.

Comment: But I'm out of this thread. You people do with this whatever you think is appropriate.

Comment: @MattN. That's what I'm getting at...

Comment: @YACP: "Good old times" or "good old days" is a cliché in popular culture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_old_days. I am sure that Matt N don't actually think that it is good when people are trying to cheat.

Comment: I have to wonder at a university which has invigilators who do not notice people typing in an exam. Can someone not invent a `temporary lock' for such questions: lock suspect questions for $3$ hours. If you need help and cannot wait $3$ hours then...well, I certainly don't want to answer your question...

Comment: Don't forget the take at home exams...we had a couple of those here too

Comment: Since Maria asked a question about this group 21 hours earlier, he/she/they are unlikely to be actually sitting an exam. It's more likely to be a take home assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try $(26)(34)\circ(37)(45)$. And figure out why it belongs to the group.